# Poor SSD RAID0 write performance, alignment on raid?

Tags: partitioning, ssd, raid, gparted, fdisk

We have Samsung840Pro 512gb x2 connected to the motherboard's c600 6gbps SATA3.0 ports. The RAID partitions use 100% of each disk:

```
user@blockparty ~ $ sudo fdisk -lu /dev/sdb

Disk /dev/sdb: 512.1 GB, 512110190592 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 62260 cylinders, total 1000215216 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000xxxxx

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048  1000214527   500106240
```

(/dev/sda has the same layout)

When I write a file using dd:

```
user@blockparty ~ $ dd count=1k bs=8M if=/dev/zero of=benchfile.bin
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
8589934592 bytes (8.6 GB) copied, 32.341 s, 266 MB/s
```

That's 2gbps. Not exactly blowing my socks off here.

Is the problem our raid partition boundaries?

```
user@blockparty ~ $ sudo fdisk -lu /dev/md0

Disk /dev/md0: 1024.2 GB, 1024216530944 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 124520 cylinders, total 2000422912 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 524288 bytes / 1048576 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00013891

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/md0p1              63  1992220649   996110293+  83  Linux
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/md0p2      1992220650  2000413799     4096575    5  Extended
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/md0p5      1992220713  2000413799     4096543+  82  Linux swap / Solaris
Partition 5 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

More info:

```
user@blockparty ~ $ sudo mdadm -D /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Thu Apr 24 13:50:42 2014
     Raid Level : raid0
     Array Size : 1000211456 (953.88 GiB 1024.22 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Thu Apr 24 13:50:42 2014
          State : clean 
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

     Chunk Size : 512K

           Name : ubuntu-test:0
           UUID : a4e7ead8:fc9c14e1:70bad27e:78a91cbe
         Events : 0

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        1        0      active sync   /dev/sda1
       1       8       17        1      active sync   /dev/sdb1
```

Comment: Can you test raw performance of a drive? _dd count=1k bs=8M if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda_

Comment: Won't writing to the raw block device cause data loss?

Comment: Yes, obviously do not do it if you have important data on the device. But it would be a useful test to do, as it would potentially eliminate the RAID layer and partitioning as the source of the performance issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of my software engineers said he had to update his BIOS to get decent SSD transfer speeds. Being a SuperMicro product, we had upgraded the IPMI we when received the board but apparently there is *also* BIOS firmware that's separate.

We upgraded the BIOS to the latest, and ***boom*** 1.2GB/s hdparm test. Moral up the story? Update your crap.

We need to upgrade the SSD firmware on the individual drives as well... save that for a night when we're feeling completely confident. Thank you for everyone that answered, you helped us get down the right path.

Answer (score 1):

What did you use to partition /dev/md0?  Any partitioning tool in the last several years should have started the first partition on sector 2048, not 63, which does cause an alignment problem.

Comment: The default one in ubuntu during the setup. Is there a way to shift the partitions?

Comment: You could try *gparted*. I am not sure how well it works to resize and relocate raid partitions. Recommend backup up your data. If gparted is not successful, then you will probably have to start from scratch and repartition the drive manually, testing the performance at each stage to make sure there is no decline. If it turns out that there is a bug in the Ubuntu partitioning tool, then open a bug with Ubuntu.